# Determine if 3 polar coordinates define an ellipse centred at the origin

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates

Is it possible to determine if three known polar coordinates $r(0)$, $r(\frac{\pi}{4})$ and $r(\frac{\pi}{2})$ define an ellipse centred at the origin?

Correct me if I'm not wrong, but this translates to finding $a$, $b$ and $\theta_{0}$ so that the following is true for $r(0)$, $r(\frac{\pi}{4})$ and $r(\frac{\pi}{2})$:

$r\left( \theta  \right)=\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^{2}\sin ^{2}\left( \theta -\theta _{0} \right)+b^{2}\cos ^{2}\left( \theta -\theta _{0} \right)}}$

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, your polar equation is correct.

Comment: That's cool. But the question is: does it have a unique solution?

Comment: Well, you could obtain as well a hyperbola or a couple of lines. It depends on the values of $r(0)$, $r(\pi/4)$, $r(\pi/2)$.

Comment: I'm assuming that these are constant positive generic values, that is: $r(0)=A$, $r(\pi /4)=B$, $r(\pi /2)=C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of an ellipse centered at the origin can be written as:
$$
Ax^2+2Cxy+By^2=1,
$$
where numbers $A$, $B$ and $C$ must satisfy: $AB-C^2>0$. Insert here the coordinates of the three given points $P_1=(r(0),0)$, $P_2={r(\pi/4)\over\sqrt2}(1,1)$, $P_3=(0, r(\pi/2))$ and solve for $A$, $B$ and $C$. If $AB-C^2>0$ then you have an ellipse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess that's the right direction. Is this equation valid for ellipses rotated around the z-axis?

Comment: Yes, it holds for a generic ellipse centered at $(0,0)$.

Comment: I guess this solves everything. Thank you very much!